# JsonReaderException during deserialization of a collection with nested list

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Json.NET to deserialize a list that contains a list my class is as follows. However, I am getting an exception saying Illegal character now I presume it will be because I need data around something if so can someone help me, please.

```
public class DeliverysItems
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryDriverId { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }        
    public int hasBeenDelivered { get; set; }
    public List<DeliverItemLines> DeliveryLines { get; set; }
}

public class DeliverItemLines
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public string StockDescription { get; set; }

    public bool isDamaged { get; set; }

    public bool isMissing { get; set; }

    public int Status  { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here you will see is an example of the data returned from the web api 2 created in .net c# with dapper.

> [{"id":1,"OrderNumber":null,"CustomerName":null,"DeliveryDriverId":1,"OrderTotal":100.00,"TelephoneNumber":"2393029023","EmailAddress":"test@test.com","hasBeenDelivered":0,"DeliveryLines":[{"id":1,"ItemNumber":null,"StockCode":"ST233202","StockDescription":"MopBoxes","isDamaged":false,"isMissing":false,"Status":0,"Qty":0.0,"Price":23.00},{"id":2,"ItemNumber":null,"StockCode":"ST232032","StockDescription":"WashingUpLiqud","isDamaged":false,"isMissing":false,"Status":0,"Qty":0.0,"Price":24.99}]}]

This is the function I use to retrieve the said above in my app.

```
private HttpClient _client;
public async Task<String> GetDeliverysFromAPi()
{
    var content = "";
    _client = new HttpClient();

    var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.31.65:81/api/Deliverys/"); // Your url is here

    try
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return content;
}
```

As you can see however I am getting the below error when I debug it I am using json.net by the way.

This is how I am encoding the above using dapper.net

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    string retJson;
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeliveryGocs"].ToString();

    string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Deliverys AS A INNER JOIN DeliveryLines AS B ON A.id = B.DeliveryId;";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        var orderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, DeliverysItems>();

        var list = connection.Query<DeliverysItems, DeliverItemLines, DeliverysItems>(
            sql,
            (order, orderDetail) =>
            {
                DeliverysItems orderEntry;

                if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.id, out orderEntry))
                {
                    orderEntry = order;
                    orderEntry.DeliveryLines = new List<DeliverItemLines>();
                    orderDictionary.Add(orderEntry.id, orderEntry);
                }

                orderEntry.DeliveryLines.Add(orderDetail);
                return orderEntry;
            })
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

        retJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(retJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
}
```

The Exception that is caused is as follows.

> {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002ac] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:1776    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:419    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs:1238    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean
>   hasConverter) [0x0004a] in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs:1195
>   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:196
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00046]
>   in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:907    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
>   reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:886    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value,
>   System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   [0x0002d] in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:830    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in
>   /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:786    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
>   [0x00000] in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:719    at
>   App1.Views.DeliveryPage.OnAppearing () [0x00015] in
>   D:\Projects\Mobile\New
>   folder\App1\App1\App1\Views\DeliveryPage.xaml.cs:95 }

Line 95 is the line where I am doing the deserlization to the list object. The to string is being used to ensure an object does not get returned.

This is how I am calling my deserlization method.

```
string content = GetDeliverysFromAPi(); //Sends a GET request to the specified Uri and returns the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation
List<DeliverysItems> _deliveryItems =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeliverysItems>>(content); //Deserializes or converts JSON String into a collection of Post
```

---

The below answer marked was indeed correct I was able to get the data by adjusting my method as per below.

```
public DeliveryDataStore()
{

        Task<string> callTask = Task.Run(() => GetDeliverysFromAPi());
        // Wait for it to finish
        callTask.Wait();
        // Get the result
        string content = callTask.Result;

        //Sends a GET request to the specified Uri and returns the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation
         deliverysItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeliverysItems>>(content); //Deserializes or converts JSON String into a collection of Post


 }
```

Comment: I believe this is because there is some circular dependency in your nested objects.

Comment: Its not as the data displays ok when calling the api so how could it be when I am in the app.

Comment: After changing your model structure, I was able to deserialize your JSON. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vsbo0F

Comment: @RahulSharma but I dont want it be callled RootOjbect what since is that to another developer comming along ?.And also why would one need to change ints to objects

Comment: @dbc the to string is irelivant here but the adjustments have been made to the question

Comment: @dbc please see above edit thanks you for helping e

Comment: Are you getting proper json in `content` variable?

Comment: yes the json content is shown above in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method `GetDeliverysFromAPi()` returns a `Task<String>`:

```
public async Task<String> GetDeliverysFromAPi() { /* Contents omitted */ }
```

But in the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55676834/1) of the [calling code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKTCs.png) you are attempting to get the returned string by simply calling `Task<TResult>.ToString()`.

```
string content = GetDeliverysFromAPi().ToString();
```

However, `Task<TResult>` does not override `ToString()` so this simply returns the full type name `` "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" `` (demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3Thw9)).

Instead, use [`Task<TResult>.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result) to get the result:

```
string content = GetDeliverysFromAPi().Result;
```

Note the [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result) for `Result` from the docs:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.
>
> Once the result of an operation is available, it is stored and is returned immediately on subsequent calls to the Result property.

Working demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQ13GH).

Incidentally, in your edited question you do

```
string content = GetDeliverysFromAPi(); //Sends a GET request to the specified Uri and returns the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation
```

This won't even compile, so is likely a typo in the question; see demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZz4yT).

Comment: Thank you for your help I hope the minus vote goes away, It was indeed the issue please see my edit above I wrapped it up in a task run method and worked a treat thanks

Comment: @rogue39nin - the vote wasn't from me.  But in your most recent edit you're now wrapping `GetDeliverysFromAPi` in another task: `Task.Run(() => GetDeliverysFromAPi());`  I'm not sure what you will get wrapping a task in another task, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: i thought it was becasue i cant seem to mark the class as async

Comment: Classes aren't async, methods are async.  See [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293).